# Cocoa Textured Window in Qt

Tags: cocoa, macos, qt

I am using Qt to develop a cross platform application. I am trying to replicate the look and feel of the left two windows (A HUD window and a textured window) but so far I can't see how to get any kind of window except for the right most window. Does anybody have any idea how to replicate those type windows?

[alt text http://th30z.netsons.org/wp-content/uploads/cocoa-windows-105.png](http://th30z.netsons.org/wp-content/uploads/cocoa-windows-105.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Transmission](http://transmissionbt.com). They have a platform independent background process and write the interface in native libraries for every platform. That's how they ensure a good looking application on all 3 platforms.

If you don't want to do the extra work there are some things provided by Qt:

- [`QMainWindow::setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true)`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmainwindow.html#unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac-prop)
- [`QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacBrushedMetal, true`)](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)
- Use [`QMacCocoaViewContainer`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmaccocoaviewcontainer.html) to encapsulate a unified window, but you have to use it with Objective-C. This would make it much harder to maintain a cross-platform application.

The easiest way would probably be to go and [hack the Qt source](http://qt.gitorious.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I think a [QMacNativeWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmacnativewidget.html) will allow you do do what you want.  Although, if you're writing this only on OS X it might be better to just make it a Cocoa app.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested just making a Cocoa app.

Comment: It is not a mac only application it is cross platform. But I want some of the dialog boxes to have a mac look and feel using the HUD window. I'll use regular dialog boxes for the windows platform.

Answer (score -4):

Textured/HUD windows aren't possible in a cross-platform way as they are OS X-only.

The only solution that I can think of is to switch to Cocoa - or abandon the idea of HUD/Textured windows altogether and focus on making something that works on all platforms.

Comment: Technically, there is also no way to make a window across all platforms, or draw a button. Frameworks tend to work around that issue by providing enough features on enough platforms to feel native...